# Log all unhandled exceptions

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1

Every time when an unhandled exception occurs the VS show me debugger on file `App.g.i.cs`:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
#endif
```

As I know this file is automatically generated and I can not make any changes in it.

But I want to log all unhandled exceptions to the text file.  Where is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your own [UnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception.aspx) handler in your App class (app.xaml.cs) and log from there. Note that not all exceptions can be handled, but this will catch the globally handleable ones.

See [App-level exception handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn532194.aspx#app-level_exception_handling) for more information.